# Client-side changes don't apply after deployment the AMP

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

I made changes to the `people-finder.js` script to change the sort order, and locally everything works well. To override the functionality, I used the following directory structure and Maven-based SDK to generate AMP file:

[image]

As I expected, locally everything works fine and I can see my changes:

[image]

Next, I deploy the AMP file on the remote server, as described here: [Install the AMP file](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-tutorials-simple-module-install-amp.html)

And here I do not see my changes:

[image]

Directory `/opt/alfresco-community/tomcat/webapps/share/components/people-finder` also contains the scripts without changes.

And thus, sorting does not work as I need.

*Additional information:* I unpacked the AMP file and not found there branch `/web/components/`... Of course, `people-finder.js` and `people-finder-min.js` is not present there also.

What could be the reason?

Comment: have you applied that amp forcefully? if same name file reside in either alfresco.war or share.war then to override we need to apply amps forcefully.

Comment: at the time of applying amp ,if any one file from amps exists in either of war then it will gives error and amps not apply.

Comment: but once apply it force fully then check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134766/discussion-between-sanjay-patel-and-aleksey-bykov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was required is to add a parameter `-force`:

```
sudo java -jar bin/alfresco-mmt.jar install amps/some-customization-share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp tomcat/webapps/share.war -force
```

Thank you very much Sanjay Patel for your assistance!

These discussions can also be useful:

- [Client-side changes don't apply after deployment the AMP](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/228008-is-there-a-way-to-control-the-sorting-order-in-the-users-search-interface)
- [Files inside src/main/amp/web folder aren't packaged inside the resulting amp file](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/176)
- [Modifications of original client-side files are not picked up](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/327)